# PInvoke code usage in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have the following C# code that uses DLLImport.

```
using System;

namespace LvFpga {
  class RegTest 
  {

    [DllImport("kernel32")]    
    public extern static int LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]    
    public extern static bool FreeLibrary(int hLibModule); 

    public static bool IsDllRegistered(string DllName)    
    {    
      int libId = LoadLibrary(DllName);
      if (libId>0) FreeLibrary(libId);
      return (libId>0);    
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLn(IsDllRegistered("msdia100.dll"));
    }
  }
}
```

When I simply run `csc CSCODE.cs` I got the errors.

```
regtest.cs(7,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllImport' could not be found (are you
        missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
regtest.cs(7,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllImportAttribute' could not be found
        (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
regtest.cs(9,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllImport' could not be found (are you
        missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
regtest.cs(9,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DllImportAttribute' could not be found
        (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What's wrong? What might be added in options?

Comment: You need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` after `using System;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Moreover, there is no function "Console.WriteLn".  You need

```
Console.WriteLine(IsDllRegistered("msdia100.dll"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the top of the file:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Your declarations are wrong, this won't work on a 64-bit operating system. Get the right ones from the pinvoke.net website.  Also add error checking, SetLastError property.