# C# attributes not recognised

Tags: c#, attributes

This must be a silly question: I am learning C# here, and I am trying to build a dll which has an iniFile class. the code is direct copy from [Code source is here](http://www.dotnet-snippets.com/dns/read-and-write-ini-files-SID574.aspx)

This project fails to build with error "the type or namespace 'DllImportAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". The error flags at

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
```

If I comment the attributes out, the build goes well. It must be setting somewhere to resolve this. Any suggestion is welcome..thx

--update--
thanks!

Comment: have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970106/pinvoke-code-usage-in-c-sharp and tried the suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` is at the top of your file.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have a using for:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices
```